# Property displayed only when using the *ngIf directive

Tags: angular

The problem: a property is displayed only using the ***ngIf** directive.

In **list-folder.component.ts** file, we retrieve the folders:

```ts
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.service.getFolders().subscribe((res: Folder[]) => {
    this.listfolders = res;
  });
}
```

In **list-folder.component.html** file:

```html
<div *ngFor="let folder of listfolders">
  <info-folder [folder]="folder"></info-folder>
</div>
```

In **info-folder.component.ts** file:

```ts
@Input()
public folder : Folder;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.women = this.folder.person.filter(
    person => person.type === 'woman'
  );
  this.men = this.folder.person.filter(
    person => person.type === 'man'
  );
}
```

In **info-folder.component.html** file:

```html
<person-detail [person]="women[0]"></person-detail>
<person-detail [person]="men[0]"></person-detail>
```

In **person-detail.component.ts** file, I retrieve a Person Object:

```ts
@Input()
public person: Person;
```

I have put a **console.log** in the **ngOnInit** and I can see the person object with the name filled:

```ts
{ personId: 2, type: man, name: Fox }
```

In **person-detail.component.html**, if I use the ***ngIf** directive, the name is well displayed:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="person.name">
  {{ person.name}}
</ng-container>
```

But without the ***ngIf**:

```html
{{ person.name}}
```

The name is not displayed. I don't understand why.

Comment: You could try changing `{{ person.name }}` with `{{ person?.name }}`. The `?` operator asserts that the data is not null before even trying to get the property you want

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: @Askirkela I tried that but it didn't changed anything

Comment: @calembredaine can u please create a demo on stackblitz.com ? It would help us debug better. Otherwise we can only guess

Comment: @SheikAlthaf no errors in the console

Comment: In your `<ng-container *ngIf="person.nom">  {{ person.name }} </ng-container>` could it be relevant that one is `person.nom` while the other is `person.name` ? Or is it just a typo in your question?

Comment: partie => person.type === 'man' // symbol person cant be found here

Comment: @Askirkela yes sorry it was a typo (I changed the code because I can't put the real one)

Answer (score 0):

This is a typo:

```
this.men = this.folder.person.filter(
  partie => person.type === 'man' // should be person => person.type === 'man'
);
```

and

```
<ng-container *ngIf="person.nom"> // *ngIf="person"
  {{ person.name}}
</ng-container>
```

Additionally console.log is not showing the correct person as it is showing no type of person i.e. man or woman:

```
{ personId: 2, name: Fox } // no type: 'man'
```

Comment: @calembredaine can you please help me implement your code using stackblitz(https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: I am trying to reproduce on stackblitz